# Sort json hierarchical data in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tree, treeview, hierarchical-data

Here is a hierarchical data set.

```
data = [
    {
        name: "Project success",
        owner_name: "Nusaiba S.",
        created_at_in_sec: 1539089917,
        children: [
            {
                name: "Develop MVP",
                parent_name: "Project success",
                owner_name: "Nusaiba S.",
                created_at_in_sec: 1539105107,
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "Requirement Analysis",
                        parent_name: "Develop MVP",
                        owner_name: "Nusaiba S.",
                        created_at_in_sec: 1539105117
                    },
                    {
                        name: "New Feature Implement",
                        parent_name: "Develop MVP",
                        owner_name: "Nusaiba S.",
                        created_at_in_sec: 1539105119
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Added Task to Jira",
                parent_name: "Project success",
                owner_name: "Nusaiba S.",
                created_at_in_sec: 1539090003
            },
            {
                name: "Meeting with Client",
                parent_name: "Project success",
                owner_name: "Jawad S.",
                created_at_in_sec: 1539104779

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to sort this hierarchical data with following requirement -

- Sorting should be ascending or descending order
- Sorting is need for every sub-level
- Sorting should be done with a specific key

Answer (score -1):

I write a method with the sort of whole hierarchical data recursively -

```
require 'json'

def sort_tree_array(data, attr, asc = true)
  data = data.is_a?(String) ? JSON.parse(data) : data
  sorted = data.sort_by {|elem| [elem[attr]]}
  sorted = asc ? sorted : sorted.reverse
  sorted.each{ |item| item[:children] = sort_tree_array(item[:children], attr, asc) if (item[:children].nil? ? [] : item[:children]).size > 0 }
  sorted
end


# Get the sorted array with ascending order name
p sort_tree_array(data, :name)

# Get the sorted array with descending order name
p sort_tree_array(data, :name, false)

# Get the sorted array with ascending order created_at_in_sec
p sort_tree_array(data, :created_at_in_sec)

# Get the sorted array with descending order created_at_in_sec
p sort_tree_array(data, :created_at_in_sec, false)
```

Comment: Great! What is your question then?

Comment: It's one kind of Q&A.

Comment: Does this answer solve your question above? If not, paste it in the question itself and mention what exactly is the issue?